# Remove App Icon from Navigation Drawer ActionBar Does not work

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am working on an App which has design requirement to be built as it should only have the Title on the ActionBar and not the App Icon.
i tried various solutions found from StackOverflow like

```
getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    getActionBar().setIcon(null);
```

however none of these worked so far, even i tried to make a hack/fix by making a transparent ic_launcher icon and put it into manifest.xml but it causes the App installation icon make transparent.
please help

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

works perfectly in 4.4 kitkat , but showing a back arrow in downgraded version like this[image]

and i need it like this to work in every device

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its quite tricky anyhow, but i solved it,and it works like a charm in all devices.

I made a 2x2 px transparant icon and added it as

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_null_icon);
```

and removed the code

```
getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

thanks to nDroidDev for suport

Answer (score 7):

please try adding this..

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and in your theme add

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="ActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>


</style>
```

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); will make the icon ic_launcher visible which i dont want
Drawer icon is already specified in actionbarToggle constructor

Comment: i have gone through your answer but didnt work, i am using a transparent theme  getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); adds ic_lancher in ActionBar which i dont need